# How to replace text on a multiselection

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following text selected in vim using `ctrl`-`v` `e` `e`:

[image]

To delete all the text I can press `x` (or `d`) and to insert new text I can do `shift-I`, but is there a way to replace that text directly? I want all those four items to say "video frame rate" instead of video resolution. How would I do that in the most efficient way in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ctrl-v` and other magic to select the block
- press `s` or `c`
- write the text you want
- press `ESC`